# The constructor TransportClient() is undefined?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-8

I am working on elastic search using mongo db. When importing transport client it shows

> The constructor TransportClient() is undefined.

I configured it as follows:

```
package com.appointment.api.mobile.config;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:elasticsearch.properties")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.appointment.api")
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
     /*   TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.host"), Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.port")));
        client.addTransportAddress(address); */
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }


}
```

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Project:

```
Spring boot maven project.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html), there is no public default constructor for the TransportClient , you need to do something like:

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
```